# Setup authorizers.xml for secured Nifi server

Tags: https, apache-nifi

I am trying to setup a simple https security using certificates for my Nifi server. I am able to setup the secure connection by setting

`nifi.security.keystore=.../nifiuser.jks` and installing certifcates etc.

When I access through Web UI , i get :

> No applicable policies could be found. Contact the system administrator.

I think i need to configure "authorizers.xml" but I dont know how. I just want "nifiuser" to have all admin rights.

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of docs and posts that describe how to do this:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#authorizer-configuration

https://bryanbende.com/development/2018/10/23/apache-nifi-secure-cluster-setup

https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the docs. I am able to set most of it up and locally it works fine. However my server is running on a GoogleCloud VM with an external IP-address. When I try to access Nifi through that IP I get: "The request contained an invalid host header [SERVER_IP:9090] in the request". I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: This means the value of nifi.web.https.host is different from the host being used to make the request, can you try setting it to the external IP/host?

Comment: So if i set it to the external IP it does not start at all (log file says "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address"). If I set it to one of the "local dns" names from /etc/hosts file then I get the same error as before... What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you can leave it set to one of the local DNS names and try setting nifi.web.proxy.host to the external IP, this is basically saying it is "ok" if a host header is received with the external IP... it feels slightly wrong since this is was geared towards being behind a proxy, but not sure how else to make it work with your network setup

Comment: I tried it and still same error. The error page is adding the IP I put under "nifi.web.https.host" to a list of "valid host headers" ... it says:  "Valid host headers are [empty] or: 127.0.0.1 ,  localhost , [my external IP], etc."
Thanks for your efforts anyways